# PIg: how to create a categorical variable?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I am using PIG 0.12 on a large dataset, and I need to create a categorical variable such as

```
FOREACH mydata GENERATE category = 1 IF condition1
                        category = 2 IF condition2
                        category = 3 IF condition3
```

That syntax does not work. Is it possible to do that in Pig?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending to the complication of the condition, there is some solution here:

[bincond](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#arithmetic):

```
(condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false)
```

[case](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#arithmetic):

```
X = FOREACH A GENERATE f2, (
  CASE f2 % 2
    WHEN 0 THEN 'even'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'odd'
  END
);
```

[udf](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/udf.html):

```
FOREACH mydata GENERATE category_udf(field_2b_checked)
```

Comment: thanks! in the `CASE` solution can I use `matches` as a condition? It is possible to name that variable? In youe example the variable for even/odd does not have any name

Comment: @Noobie Pig does not support variables ! but all what we can do, is to assign a value to a field. Pig is just a dataflow engine.

Comment: a variable, a relation its about the same. I just mean when you write `generate x = a +2  as myvar`